# String.replace()?

Tags: java

I have to replace '/' to '\' in a String value. The given string would be like:

```
String url = "//machineName/TestFolder/SampleFile.html";
url = url.replace('/', '\\');
```

Here, the output of url is like:

```
\machineNameTestFolderSampleFile.html
```

Why is it not properly replacing the slashes? The required output should be:

```
\\machingName\TestFolder\SampleFile.html
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: try `url = url.replaceAll('////', '\\');`

Comment: I tried your code - my output is `\\machineName\TestFolder\SampleFile.html` .Its works for me. Check for any other mistakes in your code .

Comment: Your code is working fine for me too!

Comment: There's a surprisingly high number of answers already suggesting `replaceAll` or using double quotes, but what you're doing is the correct procedure: `replace` takes characters, as you've given it, and it does replace *all* the occurrences. Something else must be going on here. How are you examining the post-replace contents of `url`?

Comment: `url = url.replace('/', '\\');` gives `\\machineName\TestFolder\SampleFile.html` then what is the relevance of this question. Please recheck it.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "//machineName/TestFolder/SampleFile.html";
    url = url.replace('/', '\\');
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Output:

```
\\machineName\TestFolder\SampleFile.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
String url = "//machineName/TestFolder/SampleFile.html";
url = url.replace('/', '\\');
System.out.println(url);
```

and this is the output: `\\machineName\TestFolder\SampleFile.html`

Is it not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the replaceAll function. I think replace only replaces one instance of the string it is searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Use replaceAll() method.
url = url.replaceAll('/', '\');

Comment: '\' is reserved character so you should need a '\\' to indicate that it is a actually a backslash

Answer (score 0):

`url = url.replaceAll('/', '\\');`

Answer (score 0):

Modify single quote to double quote

url = url.replace("/", "\");